# how to config events that end editing editableCellTemplate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

On page http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.edit.directive:uiGridCell

"Events that end editing:

-Dependent on the specific editableCellTemplate

-Standards should be blur and enter keydown"

I'm using the next code to identify when action happen, but what I really need is change the end event "Blur" on a specific input on my grid.

```
$scope.$on(uiGridEditConstants.events.END_CELL_EDIT , function(event) {
                    console.log(event);
                });
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMbEQ.png) is the result when I log "event"

I haven't any specification where was pull the trigger, so i can't prevent "Blur" event